# Failure to Deploy Cloud Function When Using Wildcard in Trigger

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to deploy a cloud function that will trigger whenever a document is added to a particular collection as below:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

const Firestore = require("@google-cloud/firestore");
const firestore = new Firestore({ projectId: config.projectId });

admin.initializeApp(config);

exports.checkCapacity = functions.firestore.document("gran_canaria/las_palmas_1/miller_pendientes/{albnum}")
  .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {});
```

However this throws the Deployment failure error:

> Failed to configure trigger providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.create@firestore.googleapis.com (**gcf**.us-central1.checkCapacity)

The error clears if I remove the wildcard and change the reference to:

```
"gran_canaria/las_palmas_1/miller_pendientes/albnum"
```

I've attempted changing the method to onWrite(), deleting and re-deploying the function and checking the cloud status at https://status.cloud.google.com/ but can't find any solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to deploy successfully a Cloud Function with a trigger on an onCreate event on my Cloud Firestore.

I have been successful by imply using the provided template in the Console UI when creating the Cloud with the following:

[image]

The index.js used is the sample provided by GCP when created the function, which simply prints to the logs which document triggered the change.

Looking at the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) in Firestore, I see that you probably used the samples provided there, so maybe using the above settings will make it work for you.