# Cloud Function Deployment failure When Using Wildcard in Trigger

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

So, basically the same issue as in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57789535/failure-to-deploy-cloud-function-when-using-wildcard-in-trigger) except I'm using Python and the accepted answer didn't help.

Using the provided template in the Console UI:

```
def hello_firestore(event, context):
    """Triggered by a change to a Firestore document.
    Args:
         event (dict): Event payload.
         context (google.cloud.functions.Context): Metadata for the event.
    """
    resource_string = context.resource
    # print out the resource string that triggered the function
    print(f"Function triggered by change to: {resource_string}.")
    # now print out the entire event object
    print(str(event))
```

with a wildcard in the trigger path:

```
'emails/{wildcard}'
```

I'm getting the below error:

> Deployment failure: Failed to configure trigger
>   providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.create@firestore.googleapis.com
>   (**gcf**.us-central1.presignups-counter)

Similarly as in the referenced question, the error clears when removing the wildcard from the trigger resource:

```
'emails/wildcard'
```

EDIT: here is a screenshot of the Function Details:

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to show exactly what you're doing in the console.  We need to be able to see all the exact values you're providing

Comment: @DougStevenson screenshot added, let me know if anything else needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to deploy the cloud function using : `emails/{wildcard}` and not `'emails/{wildcard}'`.

The reason for that is that when the document path is added in the UI then it should be without the single quotes. When it's in the code, then it should be in single quotes. More information [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore)